# How do I determine what version of readline bash is using?

Tags: bash, readline

How do I determine what version of readline I am using in my bash session?

I am wondering specifically because I appear to have the readline library 6.3, but the `set enable-bracketed-paste on` in my `.inputrc` is working, even though that feature was only added in readline 7.0.

I am using bash 4.4.0 on macOS 10.11 (installed with Fink).

Comment: According to [this site](https://cirw.in/blog/bracketed-paste), `bash` 4.4 uses `readline` 7.

Comment: does osx/fink provide `ldd`?  if so `ldd /path/to/bash | grep readline` should tell you exactly what libreadline is loaded.

Comment: @quixotic on macOS it's `otool -L` (which comes with the developer tools). But I tried that on bash, but it didn't list a link to readline, just ncurses, intl, and iconv. So I'm wondering maybe if bash statically links readline, which would explain why it apparently is using 7.0 even though I have 6.3.

Comment: @asmeurer bash is dynamically linked on my platform, so the question becomes how has Fink packaged it.  (assuming you installed the official Fink package.)  you can probably get their source package and default compilation options on their package db. http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/

Answer (score 4):

There is [no generally reliable method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124571/get-list-of-static-libraries-used-in-an-executable) of determining the version of a statically linked library. However, in this case, I believe you can use the value of the `rl_readline_version` global variable.

> `readline.h` defines a C preprocessor variable that should be treated as an
>   integer, `RL_READLINE_VERSION`, which may be used to conditionally compile
>   application code depending on the installed Readline version. The value is a
>   hexadecimal encoding of the major and minor version numbers of the library,
>   of the form 0x*MMmm*. *MM* is the two-digit major version number; *mm* is
>   the two-digit minor version number. For Readline 4.2, for example, the value
>   of `RL_READLINE_VERSION` would be `0x0402`.

https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC25

As of bash-2.05a and later, this is exposed as `rl_readline_version` as you can see here:

```
int rl_readline_version = RL_READLINE_VERSION;
```

https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/NEWS?id=d233b485e83c3a784b803fb894280773f16f2deb#n1542

The easiest way I know to check this is [with a debugger like `gdb`](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2005-12/msg00003.html). For example:

```
$ gdb bash
(gdb) print /x (int) rl_readline_version
$1 = 0x700
```

This means that my version of `bash` is running readline version 7.0.

In case you are curious, the readline maintainer has explained the reason for static linking on Mac OS X here:

> 19. There is special handling to ensure the shell links against static
>          versions of the included readline and history libraries on Mac OS X;
>          Apple ships inadequate dynamic libreadline and libhistory "replacements"
>          as standard libraries.

https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NOTES

Since `readline` is statically linked on Mac OS X, `ldd` and `otool` will not be helpful. However, for completeness, I will show you how it looks on Linux. Here is what mine looks like on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
$ ldd /bin/bash
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffeb83c3000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007fbcd7d57000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fbcd7b53000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbcd7762000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fbcd829b000)
```

As you can see, the `ldd` output is also unhelpful in this case. So instead I used `strace`:

```
$ strace -o strace.log -f bash
# Have to do stuff with interactive mode; `bash -c exit` won't do it.
$ exit
```

I believe the corresponding `dtrace` command would be:

```
$ dtrace -o dtrace.log -f bash
```

but I haven't tried it, so I can't say for sure. At this point, I can just grep the logfile for `readline`:

```
$ grep readline strace.log
strace.log:30194 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.7", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

So on Ubuntu 18.04 it is readline version 7, as expected.

```
$ dlocate -F '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.7'
libreadline7:amd64: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.7.0
libreadline7:amd64: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.7
$ apt-cache policy libreadline7
libreadline7:
  Installed: 7.0-3
  Candidate: 7.0-3
  Version table:
 *** 7.0-3 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
gdb -quiet -ex 'print /x (int) rl_readline_version' -ex 'quit' bash
# Outputs: $1 = 0x602 (Readline Version 6.02)
```

This is reduced [nathaniel-m-beaver answer](https://superuser.com/a/1450272/759736)

Answer (score -2):

Not sure how committed you are to using fink, but there is another package manager for macOS, and it' called homebrew and can be found [here](https://brew.sh/) or at [http://brew.sh](https://brew.sh/) which allows you to run more recent versions of programs, a la BASH, etc etc.

To install homebrew  you simply copy / paste a URL into your preferred terminal, and then run the command `brew install bash`.

I literally had the same problem as you, and creating an inputrc file and linking it to `~/.inputrc` from my [dotfiles repo](https://github.com/ipatch/dotfiles/blob/master/config/inputrc) I was able to prevent snippets from automagically  running  the shell .

Once you have all that going, try copying / pasting [the following snippet](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/6533/print-all-256-colors-for-testing-term-or-for-a-quick-reference) in your terminal, and it shouldn't run until you press the enter key if everything is setup properly.

cheers 
Chris

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question (how to tell what version of readline bash is using). And yes, I know about homebrew. I prefer fink for various reasons.